# Pass pointer by reference to function

Tags: c, pointers

**a.c**

```
#include "b.h"

typedef struct line_details {
    int line_num;
    char type[20];
} line_details;

line_details* ptr = NULL;
ptr = (*line_details) malloc(sizeof(line_details));

int x = 5;

do_something(x, &ptr);
```

**b.c**

```
void do_something(int n, line_details* ptr)
{
    /* some code */
}
```

**b.h**

```
void do_something(int n, line_details* ptr);
```

I want to pass to function `do_something` the address of the pointer and not just the copy of the pointer. When I do so, i get `incompatible pointer type error`. Why?

Comment: "Pointer by reference" in C translates to `**` pointers.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the pointer by reference? Do you want to change the pointer itself in `do_something`?

Comment: @WernerHenze No. I want to change the struct's members

Comment: A regular pointer will suffice for that.

Comment: @WernerHenze And if I want to change the pointer itself too, how should i pass the pointer?

Comment: C doesn't have the concept of "passing by reference". There is only pass by value and pass by pointer.

Comment: @Losnikov If you just need to access the data in the struct, then pass the struct by value or by reference (`line_details l` or `line_details *pl`). If you need to change the pointer to the struct, for example because this is an allocation or free function, then pass the pointer by reference (`line_details **ppl`).

Comment: Move `typedef struct line_details ...` to b.h

Comment: To answer the "why pass a pointer to a pointer" question - this can happen if you are working with multi-dimensional arrays or if you had a reason to change the actual pointer itself, say allocating memory and returning a new pointer.  Going star crazy is not a good practice - see https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: @WernerHenze And if I want to pass the pointer by reference again from `do_something` to another `function`, for example, for allocation or free, what should be the signature of `function` and what to pass to `function`?

Comment: @Losnikov As said. If `function` shall change the pointer it needs `line_details ** ppl`. If `do_something` might call `function` then `do_something` requires `line_details ** ppl` so it can pass this `ppl` to `function`. I'll wrap that up in an answer.

Comment: @WernerHenze So `do_something` passes `ppl` or `&ppl` to `function`?

Comment: @Losnikov Please see my answer for some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature depends on what the function is supposed to do with the pointer. Here are some examples.

```
// Wants to change the pointer, so needs a pointer to the pointer.
void ld_alloc(line_details** ppl) {
    *ppl = malloc(sizeof(line_details));
    ...
}

// Wants to free the pointer, so the pointer would be sufficient.
// But here we have some safety mechanism and change the pointer to NULL,
// so we need a pointer to the pointer.
void ld_free(line_details** ppl) {
    ...
    free(*ppl);
    *ppl = NULL;
}

// No need to change the pointer, so just pass it.
// No need to change the line_details, so I made it const.
void ld_print(const line_details* pl) {
   ...
}

// This function might or might not need to change the pointer, so we must
// pass a pointer to the pointer.
// We can pass this pointer to the pointer to ld_alloc, but we can also pass
// the pointer itself to ld_print.
void ld_alloc_if_null_then_print(line_details** ppl) {
    if(*ppl == NULL) {
        ld_alloc(ppl);
    }
    ld_print(*ppl);
}

line_details* ptr = NULL;
ld_alloc(&ptr);
ld_print(ptr);
ld_free(&ptr);
ld_alloc_if_null_then_print(&ptr);
```

Comment: In `ld_alloc`, `ppl` is already `**`, then why `*ppl = malloc(sizeof(line_details));`?

Comment: @Losnikov First `malloc(sizeof(line_details))` returns a `line_details*`, so the left side of the assignment must have the same type. Second you don't want to change `ppl` which would only be the local parameter variable inside `ld_alloc`. You want the side effect of changing the callers `ptr` (which is where `ppl` points to, so `*ppl`; remember: `ppl==&ptr` and `*ppl==ptr`).

Comment: In `ld_alloc_if_null_then_print` you send `ptr` which is of type `line_details*` but `ld_alloc` accepts `line_details**`? Is it a mistake or I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Losnikov That was a typo, `ptr` should have been `ppl`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your cast to `malloc` is wrong, the correct cast is `(line_details *)`. But that's if you even [want to cast malloc in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. `ptr` is already a pointer. What you're passing with `&ptr` is the address of `line_details *ptr`, in other words, a pointer to a pointer. Just pass `ptr`.
3. If your intent actually was to pass a pointer to `ptr` (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to a `line_details`), change the function signature to take `line_details **` instead, and then pass `&ptr`.

Comment: Isn't line_details a struct?

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in the code as below.

- If you want to typecast the pointer returned by malloc, you have to
  tell the type of the pointer you want to typecast i.e. '''line_details*''' not '''*line_details'''
- ptr itself is a pointer. Passing ptr to a function is enough. If you pass &ptr, it is not a pointer. It is address of pointer.

Modified program is as below.

```
#include "b.h"

typedef struct line_details {
    int line_num;
    char type[20];
} line_details;

line_details* ptr = NULL;
ptr = (line_details *) malloc(sizeof(line_details));

int x = 5;

do_something(x, ptr);
```

If you want to pass the address of the pointer, you need to change the function also like below example.

```
do_something(x, &ptr);

void do_something(int n, line_details** ptr)
{
    /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Note the `*` characters do not show up in the body of your answer without code-ifying it

Comment: Oh. Thanks Govind.

Comment: @kadina Can you please add you your answer a version where you want to pass the address of the pointer? For example, for allocation purposes?

Comment: @kadina so (in the small code) it should be `do_something(x, &ptr)`?